# Get publish post link?

Tags: publish, post-status

Is there a way I can call a link so when clicked it publishes the post via the ID I provide? I have `get_delete_post_link( $postID )` set fine, and would like to do the same to make a draft go to published, or if you can't publish post, make it pending. I also have [this code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43514/modify-front-end-delete-button-to-publish-pending-posts/43519#43519) running in my functions.php file so may be also a way to call this if a link is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I used URL parameters and created a specific function called at init:

```
    add_action( 'init', 'publish_post_status' );
    function publish_post_status($post_id){
            if (isset($_GET['publish']) && current_user_can('publish_posts')) {
                    if ($_GET['publish'] == "true") {
                            $current_post = get_post( $_GET['post_id'], 'ARRAY_A' );
                            $current_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
                            wp_update_post($current_post);
                    }
            }
            if (isset($_GET['queue'])) {
                    if ($_GET['queue'] == "true") {
                            $current_post = get_post( $_GET['post_id'], 'ARRAY_A' );
                            $current_post['post_status'] = 'pending';
                            wp_update_post($current_post);
                    }
            }
    }
```